# decide from previous setting which page will be main or launcher activity

Tags: android

i have a setting page in my application at 4th page and when i initially launch any application i will go to till fourth page and did the some setting and after that i close my application then i want to change my home page or main screen according to setting means if i want to go directly to 3rd page when i launch the application means now 3rd page is my home page or main screen then how to achieve it,
?
means is there any condition possible in android manifest file for checking the condition from setting page and then  launch my home or main page according to setting.

please i am waiting for response..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to implement a Switching Activity, set this as the main, launcher in the manifest.

Then have this activity simply

> run up (main, launcher)
>
> check the setting you have in preferences (SharedPreferences)
>
> load the according page (1,2,3,4) (startActivity(new Intent))
>
> close itself down (call finish(); on itself)

As long as you keep this activity lightweight know one will even notice it loading and it will appear like a different screen is the 'home page' dependant on your settings.